# generate user variable from email variable with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(email = c(
      "user1@email.com", "user2@othermail.org"
    )), class = "data.frame", .Names = "email", row.names = c(NA,-2L)
  )
```

I want to generate a new variable, `user`. I tried this:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(user=strsplit(email, split = '@'))
```

But I would like user to be just a character variable with the user instead of a list with to elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, email, into=c('user', 'com'), 
                   sep="@", remove=FALSE) %>% 
       select(-com)
#                 email  user
# 1     user1@email.com user1
# 2 user2@othermail.org user2
```

Or as @docendo discimus mentioned, `extract` can also be used by specifying the characters to be extracted  as a new column within a capture group (`(.*)`) followed by all others to be removed (i.e. `@` and one of more characters (`.*`))

```
extract(df1, email, "user", "(.*)@.*", remove = FALSE)
```

---

Using the OP's code, the `strsplit` output will be a `list`.  If need to extract the first element from each of the `list` elements, use `lapply`

```
 df1 %>%
    mutate(user=lapply(strsplit(email, split = '@'),"[[", 1))
```

Comment: Or  `extract(df1, email, "user", "(.*)@.*", remove = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use base R as well and just remove the characters you don't want.

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(email = c(
      "user1@email.com", "user2@othermail.org"
    )), class = "data.frame", .Names = "email", row.names = c(NA,-2L)
  )

df2 <- df1
df2$user <- gsub("@.*", "", df1$email)
df2
#                 email  user
# 1     user1@email.com user1
# 2 user2@othermail.org user2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make a small modification to your original code by just selecting the first element of each list returned from `strsplit`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(user=lapply(strsplit(email, split = '@'), "[", 1))
```